# Ошибка подключения к SMB по cifs

Tags: javascript, node.js, samba, smb

кто может помочь не могу подключиться к смб выдает такую ошибку что бы я не делал
заранее спасибо

```html
const SMB2 = require('v9u-smb2');

  const smb2Client = new SMB2({
    share: '\\\\samba.server\\FOLDER\\DISK\\c$',
    port: 445,
    domain: 'my.domen',
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
  });

  async function run(){
    smb2Client.readFile('fileTest.txt', function(err, content) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(content);
    }); 
  } run()
```

```
Error: STATUS_USER_SESSION_DELETED (0xC0000203) : The remote user session has been deleted.
    at SMB2Forge.request (/home/u8802/app/testdisk/node_modules/v9u-smb2/lib/tools/smb2-forge.js:39:15)
    at /home/u8802/app/testdisk/node_modules/v9u-smb2/lib/tools/smb2-connection.js:108:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/u8802/app/testdisk/node_modules/v9u-smb2/lib/tools/message.js:15:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/u8802/app/testdisk/node_modules/v9u-smb2/lib/tools/smb2-forge.js:88:31)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  messageName: 'session_setup_step2',
  params: {},
  code: 'STATUS_USER_SESSION_DELETED'
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я ххочу подключиться к smb серверу и открыть файл, мне пишет что Сеанс удаленного пользователя был удален. Но они верны так как по этим же данным я подключаюсь к почте